# A^T*A sparse product, results Store in Dense Matrix / Eigen Lib

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

```
SparseMatrix<double> matA(rows, cols);
SparseMatrix<double> ATA(rows, cols);
...
ATA = (SparseMatrix<double>(matA.transpose()) * matA).pruned();
//.triangularView<Lower>();
```

If I want to store results to Dense matrix for ex. `DATA = ...`, it returns very strange error of pruned function.

2. smaller question:

If I use `.triangularView<Lower>();` this store in the heap only `n/2+n` elements of (ATA OR DATA) in dynamic allocation?

LOG:

```
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h: In function 'void Eigen::internal::sparse_sparse_product_with_pruning_impl(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, ResultType&, const typename ResultType::RealScalar&) [with Lhs = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Rhs = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, typename ResultType::RealScalar = double]':
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h:91:5:   instantiated from 'static void Eigen::internal::sparse_sparse_product_with_pruning_selector<Lhs, Rhs, ResultType, 0, 0, 0>::run(const Lhs&, const Rhs&, ResultType&, const RealScalar&) [with Lhs = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Rhs = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, Eigen::internal::sparse_sparse_product_with_pruning_selector<Lhs, Rhs, ResultType, 0, 0, 0>::RealScalar = double]'
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseProduct.h:121:9:   instantiated from 'void Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Lhs, Rhs>::evalTo(Dest&) const [with Dest = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, LhsNested = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, RhsNested = const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&]'
jni/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:522:101:   instantiated from 'static Derived& Eigen::internal::assign_selector<Derived, OtherDerived, false, false>::evalTo(ActualDerived&, const ActualOtherDerived&) [with ActualDerived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, ActualOtherDerived = Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&>, Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, OtherDerived = Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&>]'
jni/Eigen/src/Core/Assign.h:571:98:   instantiated from 'Derived& Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator=(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&>, Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]'
jni/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:453:7:   instantiated from 'Derived& Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::operator=(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&>, Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]'
jni/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:184:35:   instantiated from 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>& Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::operator=(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::SparseSparseProduct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>&>, _Scalar = double, int _Rows = -0x00000000000000001, int _Cols = -0x00000000000000001, int _Options = 0, int _MaxRows = -0x00000000000000001, int _MaxCols = -0x00000000000000001, Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]'
jni/After.cpp:429:36:   instantiated from here
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h:50:3: error: 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>' has no member named 'reserve'
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h:69:5: error: 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>' has no member named 'startVec'
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h:71:7: error: 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>' has no member named 'insertBackByOuterInner'
jni/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSparseProductWithPruning.h:73:3: error: 'class Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>' has no member named 'finalize'
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/com_jp_algi_CoreC/After.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: What is the error that pruned returns?

Comment: I cut off the command .pruned() and error is the same :

Comment: IT looks like there is no support in EIgen with this, OR there can be some hack with pruned double raNGE LIMIT.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, it would be a lot easier for people to help you (and you to help yourself) if you would prepare a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I did below. For me, it helped me understand what you tried to ask. For you, it would help you understand your problem better and maybe even solve it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SparseMatrix<double> a(3,3), ata;
    a.coeffRef(1,2) = 0.;
    a.coeffRef(1,1) = 2.;
    a.coeffRef(1,0) = 6.;
    a.coeffRef(0,1) = 1.;
    cout << a << endl;
    ata = (a.transpose() * a).pruned();
    cout << ata << endl;
    ata = (SparseMatrix<double>(a.transpose()) * a).pruned();
    cout << ata << endl;
    MatrixXd dense = ata.toDense();
    cout << dense << endl;
    /*****************************************************/
    // Everything works fine until this point
    /*****************************************************/

    //dense = (SparseMatrix<double>(a.transpose()) * a).pruned(); // Doesn't compile

    // Would compile if written as the following line
    dense = SparseMatrix<double>((SparseMatrix<double>(a.transpose()) * a).pruned()).toDense(); // Works
    cout << dense << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, I undestand, I didnt have so much time, but thanks for help"

Comment: and when I want to  store only,  Lower triangular part...?   dense.triangularView<Lower>();   ????

Comment: In short, no. It's almost explicit in the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__QuickRefPage.html#title14). Also, you can easily create a MCVE to check.

Comment: so the benefit is only with that, you can store to rest trinagular part another data....?

Comment: No, it _presents_ an upper/lower triangle that may have better algorithms, etc.

Comment: Ok,, my issue is  specific: so  add after .todense() .selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().....?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Formulate a (good) question and post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79297/discussion-between-user2165656-and-avi-ginsburg).